# Delete all records in a table after a certain string in a row

Tags: mysql

I am importing a table from CSV to MYSQL on a regular basis. I need to clean the table by removing all rows after a given string in the row. Each import could have different amount of records, so deleting after a set row ID will not work because the string may be on a different row next time, therefore it needs to pick out the text. 
Anyone know how this is done please?
An example below shows the different rows and text. So I need to delete all rows after 'Text d'.

```
Text a
Text x
Text k
Text d
Text a
Text u
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to remove the lines after 'Test d' through programming? If yes, then which language?
A simple solution would be to apply the regular expression and replace [\s\S]YourTargetTextHere[\s\S]+ with empty string i.e., ""

Comment: Thanks ZAO. I don't understand what you mean. I want to run a MYSQL script to clean the table after upload.

Comment: You are importing a table from CSV right? Why not delete the records not required after a certain string in the CSV and then you can import only the required rows.
For example, have a look at this sample regular expression the removes all the rows after 'Text d' https://regex101.com/r/0Sd8Oo/1

Comment: Thanks again ZAO. I would rather do it in MySQL like the answer below but I appreciate you looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an ID column and the order of the ID values are the same as the order of "delete every row after 'Text d'", you can read the ID of that specific row first:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    yourTable
Where
    yourColumn = 'Text d'
```

Then you can use the Id for a second query to delete all the following rows

```
DELETE FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    id > theSelectedIdValue
```

You might be able to use it in one query with something like this:

```
DELETE FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    id > (SELECT
              id
          FROM
              yourTable
          WHERE
              yourColumn = 'Text d')
```

However I'm not sure if this query works in MySQL.

Comment: Well done and thanks Progman. It didn't actually work:  " Table 'test' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data "   but I can copy the table and then run the query. Awesome mate.